# Put in session a browser information

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

I want to put in the PHP session an information if the client uses HTML5 or not.

My HTML5 detection is launched only 1 time and need to store the information in the PHP session, sending from HTML to PHP is easy with a simple cookie, but if the client doesn't accept cookies it's harder.

Sending a GET variable to php is a possibility but on the 1st load we don't have the information.

Or maybe there is another way to store an information without PHP that works on none-cookied browsers ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I did it differently.
Instead of detecting on the page itself that required me to call jQuery or other plugins, I call it from the main page and send the data to the called page.
Like that I got it in PHP on that page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions don't DEPEND on cookies, but they sure are a lot easier to work with. You can have PHP auto-embed the session ID into URLs for you, but it's a very nasty security hole - the user's session ID will leak onto any sites you link to via the referer, and makes it impossible to properly bookmark your site.

If you do want to chance that, then look up [trans_sid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) settings in your php configuration.

Comment: I was thinking of a detection at the beginning and do an AJAX call to set the session.

Comment: setting the session isn't a problem. If the client isn't accepting cookies, then you'll have to pass the session ID via urls/hidden form fields, which is where trans_sid comes in.